# Postgres pgx driver hangs on commit

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a function that updates records in table and requests it using pgx Postgres driver. This function hangs on commit. Is there any ideas why does it happen? Why I can't use transactions in this case?

Of course, as the query is atomic I can remove transactions. But it's still unclear—why it happens and what to do if I need a transaction.

```
func (r *Repository) GetUpdatedItems(ctx context.Context, filters []string) ([]Item, error) {
    conn, err := r.pool.Acquire(ctx)
    // error handling
    defer conn.Release()
    
    tx, err := conn.Begin(ctx)
    // error handling
    defer func() {
        closeCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
        defer cancel()
        _ = tx.Rollback(closeCtx) 
    }()

    query := fmt.Sprintf(`UPDATE %s
    SET fieldOne = $1, fieldTwo = $2
    WHERE otheField = '' OR otherField IS NULL
    RETURNING fieldOne, fieldTwo, otheField, someMoreField;`,
        r.tableName, sqlArray(aggregatesTypes))

    rows, err := conn.Query(ctx, query, filters[0], filters[1])
    // error handling
    defer rows.Close()

    var retItems []reaper.Item

    for rows.Next() {

        var fieldOne string
        var fieldTwo string
        var otheField string
        var someMoreField string
        

        if err := rows.Scan(&id, &fieldOne, &fieldTwo, &otheField, &someMoreField); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to scan item: %w", err)
        }

        item := Item{
            FieldOne:       fieldOne,
            FieldTwo:       fieldTwo,
            OtheField:      otheField,
            SomeMoreField:  someMoreField
        }

        retItems = append(retItems, item)
    }

    if err := tx.Commit(ctx); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to commit transaction: %w", err)
    }
    
    return retItems, nil
}
```

Comment: thanks! While I had prepared an example I found the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tx.Query` must be used instead of `conn.Query`.

Thanks for the help!